# Creating a function that deletes a certain character from a string. What is wrong with my program?

Tags: c++, function, while-loop

I am trying to delete all G's from a string. I need to use a pointer, but my problem is I don't know what to replace the found G's with. I did not know an empty character constant ('') would not compile. How can I remove the character keeping in line with this code?

```
   void deleteG(char cString[])
{
    char *ptr;
    ptr = cString;
    while (*ptr != '\0')
    {
        if (*ptr == 'g' || *ptr == 'G')
        {
            *ptr = ' ';
        }
        ptr++;


}
```

}

Comment: Because you only increment `ptr` when you encounter `g` or `G` in the string. What happens if it's not one of those characters hmmmmmm?

Comment: Try using string type instead of pointers.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, I think that should probably be an answer, since it's literally the answer!

Answer (score 1):

As @Captain Obvlious points out, your `while` loop never ends because unless a letter is a 'g' or 'G' it will never increment the pointer. This is fairly easy to determine if you put a breakpoint in, or even use a `std::cout` on the letter being evaluated.

The solution of course is to change your `while` loop to the following:

```
while (*ptr != '\0')
{
    if (*ptr == 'g' || *ptr == 'G')
    {
        *ptr = *(ptr+1);
    }
    ptr++;
}
```

Whilst this solves the problem of the infinite loop, an *even better* solution would be to use the standard library: [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)! Because I'm not 100% sure of what you are trying to accomplish, I'll provide two examples:

## Using the standard library to remove all upper-case letters

If your goal was to remove all upper-case characters, consider the following use of the standard library:

```
bool IsUpper(char c)
{
    return !!std::isupper(c);
}

int main()
{
    std::string test = "Hello World :D";
    test.erase(std::remove_if(test.begin(), test.end(), IsUpper), test.end());
    return 0;
}
```

This uses [`std::string::erase`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) and [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) to remove all upper-case letters from the string. `std::remove_if` takes a start and end `iterator` (we give it the start and end of our `test` string) and a predicate (our function `IsUpper`) which will be called for each element in the container (in this case, each `char`0 in the `std::string`). If the predicate (`IsUpper`) returns `true` for a `char`, that `char` is moved to the back of the container. `std::remove_if` will continue to do this until it reaches the end, where it will then return an `iterator` to the beginning of the offending characters (now at the end of the string).
This `iterator` is then used by `std::string::erase`, which takes a start and end `iterator` (similar to `std::remove_if`) and erases the elements in that range (in this case, the start of the offending characters to the end of the string).
You will be left with only "ello orld :"

Note also our predicate `IsUpper` uses another standard library function [`std::isupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isupper) to determine if a `char` is upper-case or not.

## Using the standard library to remove all *g*'s

If, like your function name `deleteG` suggests, you were trying to remove all instances of *g* from your string, consider:

```
bool IsG(char c)
{
    return c == 'g' || c == 'G';
}

int main()
{
    std::string test = "GHelgglo gWorlgGd";
    test.erase(std::remove_if(test.begin(), test.end(), IsG), test.end());
    return 0;
}
```

Similar to above, but we have swapped out our predicate (and `test` string) for a function that tells us whether a certain character is a *g* or not: aptly named `IsG`.
You will be left with "Hello World"

Comment: Note that you shouldn't use `sizeof` on an array parameter - it will not return the size of the array, as that is not known at compile time.

Comment: Thanks @TheDark, I have removed that example. I did try `sizeof(cString)` and it worked fine (or seemed to).

Comment: Note that after the second `g` in the string, you need to copy `*(ptr + 2)`.  In fact, in general, you need two pointers (or two indexes, or a pointer and an index) to do the job properly.

Comment: *"I did try sizeof(cString) and it worked fine (or seemed to)"* just fyi - it will return the size of a `char*`, rather than `strlen()` of the text.  That's because the `cString` parameter is treated as a `char*` parameter (despite the `[]` notation).  That allows the same function to process different length text during different calls.  `sizeof` does work on actual arrays where the dimension is known, such as a local array variable, or when a function parameter is passed a la `template <size_t N> void f(T (&a)[N]) { /* sizeof a "works"... */)`, but then you get an instantiation per size.

Comment: Given the test program: `int main(void)
{
    char data[] = "abcdefghijABCDEFGHIJ";
    char *ptr = data;

    printf("Before: [[%s]]\n", data);
    while (*ptr != '\0')
    {
        if (*ptr == 'g' || *ptr == 'G')
        {
            *ptr = *(ptr+1);
        }
        ptr++;
    }
    printf("After:  [[%s]]\n", data);
    return 0;
}`, the output is two lines of data: (1) `Before: [[abcdefghijABCDEFGHIJ]]` and (2) `After:  [[abcdefhhijABCDEFHHIJ]]`.  This isn't what's wanted.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm not sure I follow sorry. The question was about fixing the infinite loop which the answer addresses. What did you mean by _"this isn't what's wanted"_? I'm not sure what the OP's intention of their code is, but I pointed out I don't think their function does what they intend it to do (which I assume is to **delete** the letters) and suggested using a `std::string`

Comment: Hmmm…well, on a narrow reading of the question, yes.  But that's not entirely helpful, and it isn't clear why you chose to copy the letter after the `g` or `G` (which might itself be a `g` or `G`, though my test doesn't show that) into the place of the `g` or `G` you've detected).  So, working on the assumption that 'deleting a letter G' is the immediate problem, your code is not a bullet-proof deleter of G's.  The bigger problem is 'any alphabetic character'.  Basically, IMO, you've not gone far enough in answering the question, yet.  You're at liberty to disagree with me, of course.

Comment: To avoid all confusion, I've updated my answer to directly answer why the loop wasn't working as well as providing uses of the standard library that will solve what I believe the OP is trying to accomplish. Everybody wins.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend something like this...

```
void deleteAlpha(char cString[])
{
    const char *from = cString;
    char* to = cString;

    do
    {
        while (isalpha(*from))
            ++from;
    }
    while (*to++ = *from++);
}
```

Note that `from` iterates over the string, skipping alpha characters, while `to` tracks the location that the next non-alpha character should be "compacted" to.  The `while` loop condition carefully copies the terminating `NUL` even as it evaluates `false` and finishes the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* remove(char *s) {
    char *current = s;
    char *r = s; // 
    do {
        if ((*current < 'A') || (*current > 'Z') || (*current < 'a') || (*current > 'z')) {
            *r++ = *current;
        }
    } while (*current++ != 0);
    return s;
}
```

Comment: You might want to test that... not going to be pretty.  For a start, `if ((*current < 'A') || (*current > 'Z') || (*current < 'a') || (*current > 'z'))` will always be `true`....

Comment: There's `isalpha()` from `<ctype.h>` for testing whether a character is a letter.

Answer (score 0):

I am not much familiar with c++. Try to increment the pointer outside the if statements, not inside it. Then it will not enter in an infinite while loop

Comment: Thanks, I'm out of the infinite loop. Now I'm just looking for a better way to delete G/g characters when I find them then by replacing them with ' ' .

Comment: @JohnWrgzl I've updated my answer to show you a way to delete _g_'s from a string.